# requirejs, nginx, bower, Chrome Dev Tools: "Resource interpreted as script but transferred with MIME type text/html"

Tags: google-chrome, nginx, requirejs, bower

Chrome dev tools has started giving me the error: "Resource interpreted as script but transferred with MIME type text/html".

I've read all the StackOverflow and other googled links I could find (there are a lot of threads reporting this error), to no avail.

I am running nginx, using require.js, and updating my js packages through bower, and I'm stumped where to look to debug this.  My hunch is that something was updated with bower and this particular page didn't get tested (other pages still working).

Comment: [SOLVED] (not allowed to answer my own question for 8 hours, by which time I sincerely hope to be asleep).  I had been so focused on the Network tab of Chrome Dev Tools that I had neglected to take a close look at the nginx error log.  There was a 404 there not showing on the Chrome Dev Tools.  Not exactly sure why that causes the mime type problem, but I'm posting this solution in case somebody else hits this, or in case I forget again six months from now.